# Nginx HTTP to HTTPS redirection doesn't work

Tags: http, nginx, redirect, https

I have some question while integration web server.
My server is developed as
nginx + nodejs + azure load balancer.

Now I'm using 2 domains. But I have to redirect to one domain.
And also i have to redirect all http to https.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name {MY_DOMAIN_1};

    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/_wildcard_.{MY_DOMAIN_1}_20211208D2F14.key.pem;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/_wildcard_.{MY_DOMAIN_1}_20211208D2F14.ca-bundle.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Proxy-From {MY_DOMAIN_1};
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name {MY_DOMAIN_2} www.{MY_DOMAIN_1} www.{MY_DOMAIN_2};

    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/_wildcard_.{MY_DOMAIN_1}_20211208D2F14.key.pem;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/_wildcard_.{MY_DOMAIN_1}_20211208D2F14.ca-bundle.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    return 301 $scheme://{MY_DOMAIN_1}$request_uri;
}
```

Here is my code. I thought there is no problem..
But it doesn't work.(Only http -> https doesn't work, forward to one domain is working)
Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Start with the basic redirection below and incrementally add new lines to it.  Enabling [HTTP/2](https://http2.github.io/) is highly-recommended.

```
# http to https
server {
  listen      80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example.com;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen      443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate_key ...;
  ssl_certificate     ...;
}
```

Test with the command line to ensure the browser is not caching responses.

```
$ curl -I http://example.com/
```